# Search for a string and assign the ones it is not in the braced brace to a new string

Tags: java, string

Search for a string like this:

```
String str="[NUMBER] HELLO [AA] [hh] DAVID";
```

How can i assign the ones it is not in the braced brace to a new string.

Comment: Will the braces always surround exactly 1 word?

Comment: @superHero Do you seek the output to be `HELLO DAVID`?

Comment: @nullpointer yeah , I want to do it

Comment: That looks like an *assignment* for you to complete, using Java features you've ready learned. Since we don't know what you've learned, we can't do the assignment for you, and we *shouldn't* do the assignment for you, because then you'd learn nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @nullpointer I want to assign HELLO DAVID to another string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean by this:

```
String newStr = str.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\] ?", "");
```

Comment: Too much spoonfeeding for my taste.